# Hibernate Query Result List and Type safety?

Tags: java, hibernate, type-safety

This results in unchecked warning:

```
public List<Person> list()
{
  return sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createQuery( "FROM Person" ).list();
}
```

Already tried, without success:

```
public List<Person> list()
{
  Query query = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createQuery( "FROM Person" );
  return Collections.checkedList( query.list(), Person.class );
}
```

I do NOT want to add

```
@SuppressWarnings( "unchecked" )
```

because it wouldn't fix it...

So, how to have type safety?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At some place a conversion from the untyped list to the typed list has to happen. This conversion is `unsafe`. `Collections.checkedList` would allow you to move the annotation but not more; not very helpful here. The annotation does not "solve" the problem in a technical sense, it just tells the compiler that you know what you do. As the `Query` interface does not return typed results (for good reason) there is no way around either a warning or the SuppressWarnings annotation.

You should set the annotation and write a meaningful comment why it is justified (i.e. because the type is determined by the HQL query but the interface returns an untyped list).